# Change separator in Bibtex bibliography from comma to period

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, punctuation

I've been editing a Bibtex style, the standard [`agsm.bst`](http://www.cs.uvm.edu/~kais/LaTeX/agsm.bst), to match my university's requirements. I've managed to get everything correct, except that the style separates the year, title, and journal with commas:

> Schuster-Böckler, B., Schultz, J. and Rahmann, S. (2004), HMM Logos for visualization of protein families, *BMC Bioinformatics* 5(1),7.

I need the output to use a full stop (period) as the separator:

> Schuster-Böckler, B., Schultz, J. and Rahmann, S. (2004). HMM Logos for visualization of protein families. *BMC Bioinformatics* 5(1),7.

I'm fairly sure this isn't defined in the style file. Where is this behaviour defined, and how can I change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You concluded the posting with:

> I'm fairly sure this isn't defined in the style file. Where is this behaviour defined, and how can I change it?

Actually, this behavior *is* set in the style file, but it's not easy to find. First, make a copy of the file `agsm.bst` and name it, say, `my-agsm.bst`. Then, search for the function that starts with

```
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
```

(located on l. 59 of my copy of `agsm.bst`). A couple of lines further down, you should find:

```
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
```

Replace the comma in the second line with a period, save the file, and don't forget to specify

```
\bibliographystyle{my-agsm}
```

in your tex file. (If you've chosen a filename other than `my-agsm.bst`, you'll of course have to make the appropriate adjustment.) You'll note that there are other commas (or is that "commata"?!) in the .bst file, but those pertain to separating names of authors and editors -- settings that, according to your posting, should remain unchanged.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm happy to be proven wrong about it being defined in the style file! 

P.S. "comma" is Latin and the Latin plural is "commata". Both "commas" and "commata" are acceptable in English (but "commata" sounds way better).

Comment: No need to apologize for not being able to spot the relevant comma setting in the file `agsm.bst`! It's only with practice that one can figure out how and where bibtex-related things are done...

Comment: @mico where can I find the old agsm.bst file on a mac, running texshop? Thanks!

Comment: @marinko - Just open a terminal window and type `kpsewhich agsm.bst`. Incidentally, you've so far posted seven questions to which you've received answers, yet you've "accepted" only two answers. Please review.

Comment: @ Mico, thanks mico. will review wasn't aware about the importance of accepting answers!