# AGSM style: Period after years and collection titles, but not after chapter names?

Tags: bibtex, styles

I'm trying to get `agsm.bst` to format Harvard-style correctly (or at least the way my university requires me to do it :-) ). I have an `@InCollection` record like the following:

```
@incollection{Berndt99,
    author      = {T. J. Berndt},
    title       = {Friendships in adolescence},
    booktitle   = {Making sense of social development},
    editor      = {M. Woodhead and D. Faulkner and K. Littleton},
    year        = 1999,
    publisher   = {London: Routledge in association with the Open University},
}
```

which needs to be formatted as follows (bbl excerpt):

```
\harvarditem{Berndt}{1999}{Berndt99}
Berndt, T.~J.  \harvardyearleft 1999\harvardyearright . `Friendships in
  adolescence', in: M.~Woodhead, D.~Faulkner \harvardand\ K.~Littleton (eds)
  {\em Making sense of social development}. London: Routledge in association
  with the Open University.
```

By default, `agsm` produces

```
\harvarditem{Berndt}{1999}{Berndt99}
Berndt, T.~J.  \harvardyearleft 1999\harvardyearright , `Friendships in
  adolescence', in: M.~Woodhead, D.~Faulkner \harvardand\ K.~Littleton (eds)
  {\em Making sense of social development}, London: Routledge in association
  with the Open University.
```

I have followed the advice in [Change separator in Bibtex bibliography from comma to period](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44870/change-separator-in-bibtex-bibliography-from-comma-to-period) already, but unfortunately this replaces every separating comma with a period not just the ones I want. In particular, I now also get a period after the chapter title (`Friendships in adolescence') where I need a comma.

If I understand correctly, `agsm` manages this by tracking output state in an `output.state` variable. However, I don't understand how it does this and how I might be able to get it to differentiate these two parts of the reference.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks,

Steffen

Comment: The `agsm` and `dcu` bib styles (both part of the `harvard` package) are known to (designed to!) do some fairly funky stuff with entries with multiple authors; see, e.g., the posting [Citation in “dcu” bibliography style sometimes return “et al” other times full author list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348124/5001). Unless your university actively requires you to adhere to `agsm`'s funky settings, you're probably better off creating a new, bespoke bib style from scratch using the `makebst` utility. `makebst` will also let you customize which punctuation characters should be used where.

Comment: Thanks. I have no issue with the handling of multiple authors in `agsm`, this seems OK for my use case. I'm simply looking for a solution of the problem of period vs comma. Creating a completely fresh style seems a little overkill for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having dug into this a little bit more, I found the solution. It was indeed to do with how `output.nonnull` manages states. This is fairly confusing in that the state tracking is used to determine what delimiter to place *the next time `output.nonnull` is called.*

Here's the original code:

```
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}

STRINGS { s t f }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
      { add.period$ write$
        newline$
        "\newblock " write$
      }
      { output.state before.all =
          'write$
          { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
      }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
    if$
  s
}
```

When the year is printed, `output.state` is still in `before.all`, meaning it switches to `mid.sentence` and next time round a comma is appended. However, this same branch is reached for all other parts throughout. I changed this to add a new state `after.year`, which allowed me to mark that the year had been processed and a period is needed rather than a comma. Note that in the new code below I only need to set this state, but don't need a new if branch for checking it; the default branch already does what we want.

```
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block after.year after.collection.title }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
  #4 'after.year :=
  #5 'after.collection.title :=
}

STRINGS { s t f }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state before.all =
        {
          write$
          after.year 'output.state :=
        }
        { output.state after.block =
            { 
              add.period$ write$
              newline$
              "\newblock " write$
            }
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
            if$
            mid.sentence 'output.state :=
        }
        if$
    }
    if$
  s
}
```

I've also added an `after.collection.title` state (I could probably have reused `after.sentence`, but didn't want to mess with that), which I set in the appropriate place in `FUNCTION{incollection}` to indicate that we have just pushed the collection title onto the stack:

```
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  list.label.output
  " \harvardyearleft " list.year * "\harvardyearright " * output.nonnull
  title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.title quote "title" output.check }
    if$
    author "author" item.check
    crossref missing$
      { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
        after.collection.title 'output.state :=
        ....
```

This gives me a period after the collection title rather than a comma.